# how to turn on or off the microphoneButton with bot framework and web chat only when user click on the button?

Tags: node.js, botframework, speech-recognition, microphone, web-chat

I would like to control the activation or deactivation of the microphone button and that it is not always working once you use it

Comment: What do you mean with the activation? The microphone button provided by web-chat works/activates once you click it, so what is exactly what you what to achieve? Please provide more information

Comment: When you activate the microphone button for the first time, when the bot answers you and you have to speak again, it activates itself without having to give it, I use Direct Line Speech and Web Chat.
So I want to find some way to activate the button only when it is pressed